# why bubblesort with decreasing phase does not work?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am a beginner in C and I am trying to create a program in which I sort with the help of bubble sort algorithm the words in decreasing phase based on ASCII sum of the word
(for example the word with the largest sum of ASCII will go first and  last will be the word
with the smallest ASCII sum - that's why I use strcmp to compare the words)
but when I print the words my bubblesort algorithm does not work
What is going wrong?

My code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void swap(char **xp, char **yp)
{
    char **temp; 
    temp= xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    yp = temp;
}
 
void bubbleSort(char **arr, int n)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)                
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
           if (strcmp(arr[j] , arr[j+1])>=0)
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}

int main ()
{
    char *p[5]={"Manolas","tikinio","youssef el arabi"};
    
    bubbleSort(p,3);
    
    char **p1;
    p1=p;
    for(p1=p ; *p1 ; p1++)
    {
        printf("\nthe words are : %s", *p1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *first* step that goes wrong when you execute this?

Comment: @ Scott Hunter it does not sort the words  it does not seem to change the sequence of words

Comment: @ScottHunter I thinks it is invoked an undefined behavior

Comment: I didn't ask for the *final* result; I asked about the *first step* that goes wrong.

Comment: You might want to test your `swap` function by itself; also your use of `strcmp`.

Comment: `if (strcmp(arr[j] , arr[j+1])>=0)` ... you don't need to swap them if they are equal.

Comment: @ScottHunter You are right . I lost one word if I call only  `swap(&p[1],&p[2]);`

Comment: @Βill97 I do not see where a sum of ASCII characters is calculated.

Comment: _"the word with the largest sum of ASCII will go first and last will be the word with the smallest ASCII sum - that's why I use strcmp"_ is a non-sequitur - that is not what `strcmp()` does.  If the "sum of ASCII" is the ordering then "AAZ" would be _equal to_ "ZAA" because they have the same _sum_.  There is no standard function for that (unsurprisingly) , you'd have to implement your own.

Comment: In your `swap` function, one of the three assignment statements contains `*`  operators. Shouldn't all three have the same syntax? After all, every symbol is of the same type.

Comment: Just to clarify, tell us what the expected sorted order is.  Because "_ ASCII sum of the word_" is ambiguous.  Do you really mean that or do you simply mean alphabetical order (or reverse alphabetical order)?  And what about case-sensitivity?  Is 'm' == 'M' or not?

Comment: `strcmp(arr[j], arr[j+1]) >= 0` is always `false` because the input strings are already in the defined order.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  You are right I thought that `strcmp` compares the ASCII (I mean that every character has an ASCII value and for every word has to sum them)

Comment: @Clifford It is a completely mess I has to creare my own function which calculates the sum

Comment: @Βill97  Why would you think `strcmp()` did that.  What would be the purpose of such a function?  It is simple; if you are trying to do something that serves no practical purpose; there is no standard function for that.

Comment: @Clifford I had read that strcmp "This function compares strings character by character using ASCII value of the characters." from the following site :https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/the-strcmp-function-in-c/ but I did not understand well
That's why

Comment: @Βill97 Yes it compares, it does not "sum".  Also while it compares character-by-character it terminates at the first mismatch because then it knows the strings differ - it need go no further. For `strcmp( "AAA",  "AAZZ" ), returns >1 because the third 'A' comes before the third 'Z' in ASCII order, the fourth 'Z' is ignored.  It is about ordering, not about summing.  Summing serves no practical purpose in most conceivable applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp(arr[j], arr[j+1]) >= 0` is always `false` because the input strings are already in the correct order with respect to `strcmp()` that does not work the way you seem to think.  So `swap()` is never called.

`swap()` is incorrectly defined in any case (and caused a seg-fault when I tried it - confusingly only when `printf()` was called after the sort was complete):

```
void swap(char **xp, char **yp)
{
    char* temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
```

Your `main() routine is unnecessarily obfuscated, suggest:

```
    char* p[] = {"Manolas","tikinio","youssef el arabi"} ;
    const int count = sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p) ;
    
    bubbleSort( p, count );
    
    printf( "The words are:\n" ) ;
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", p[i] ) ; 
    }
```

Your specified sort criteria are not satisfied by `strcmp()`.  `strcmp()` returns:

```
<0  the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2
0   the contents of both strings are equal
>0  the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2
```

You need a different compare function:

```
int acsiiSumCmp( const char* a, const char* b )
{
    unsigned sum_a = 0 ;
    unsigned sum_b = 0 ;
    for( int i = 0; a[i] != 0; i++ ) sum_a += (unsigned char)a[i] ;
    for( int i = 0; b[i] != 0; i++ ) sum_b += (unsigned char)b[i] ;
    
    return sum_a - sum_b ;
}
```

Which returns >1 whhen the sum of `a` is greater than `b`, such that to achieve the ordering you have specified you need:

```
if( acsiiSumCmp( arr[j] , arr[j + 1] ) < 0 )
{
    swap( &arr[j], &arr[j + 1] ) ;
}
```

Note there is no need to swap when the terms are equal so not `>=` or `<=` as you had it, just `<` or `>` depending on the desired order.

Finally a little bit of "const-correctness" would not go amiss here, as follows:

```
void swap( const char**xp, const char** yp )
           ^^^^^           ^^^^^
```

```
void bubbleSort( const char** arr, int n)
                 ^^^^^
```

```
const char* p[] = { "ZZ", "Manolas","tikinio","youssef el arabi", "AA" } ;
^^^^^
```